# little per-mode option problem with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

Hi how can I define the `per-mode` option, that the unit in text is e.g. `50 N mm^{-2}` and not `50 N/mm^2`? I know, that I can use `\si{N.mm^{-2}}` but I want to make it automatically.

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}      

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\sisetup{                                                   
    locale=DE, 
    per-mode=fraction,
    separate-uncertainty,
    list-units=repeat,
    range-units=repeat,
    per-mode=symbol-or-fraction
}

\DeclareSIUnit\druck{\newton\per\milli\meter\squared}


\begin{document}

Test test test \SI{50}{\druck}

\begin{equation}
    \SI{86}{\druck}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You've explicitly set `per-mode=fraction`, which is exactly what you are getting

Comment: No than I have both in fraction mode.

Comment: Use the default: `per-mode=reciprocal`.

Comment: @Bernard then I have both reciprocal. I would like to have reciprocal in text and fraction in equation or math mode

Comment: In this case, you  might take as default the most used value your document, and use `\si[per-mode=…]{}{}` for the other case. Or define a new command,  e.g. `\Si` or `\sI` for the other case.